# Find out which lines are executed in C # source with a given test suite(Get code coverage)

Tags: c#, code-coverage, trace

I have a C# program like

```
public class TheMiddle
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int result;
        if (a < b)
        {
            if (c < a)
                result = a;
            else if (c > b)
                result = b;
            else
                result = c;
        }
        else
        {
            if (c < b)
                result = b;
            else if (c > a)
                result = a;
            else
                result = c;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
  }
```

and a test case like (a,b,c) = (1,2,3).
How do I know which lines of code run through the above tests?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In general, you can use  any test coverage tool for that

Comment: That is exactly code coverage, but I want a method or API to get the lines of code (I will use these lines of code later).  What I look for is similar to the settrace method in python

Comment: Do you want to check code coverage while you actual code is running ? That's a hard job, maybe you  find an open source C# code coverage tool. At runtime you don't have your source code,  I think python has ? This is more interpreting ? That's a major different approach. Code Coverage tools attach to a running process like a debugger and log each single activity. A "result" is computed after the program finished, that's why there is no demand for an API. The debugged program has usually no access to the debugger data.

Comment: You can always step into the code with a debugger...